# "unix" C++ preprocessor macro is undefined with -std=c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, unix, preprocessor, icc

**unixpreproc.cpp**

```
#ifdef unix
#warning "unix is defined"
#endif

#ifdef __unix__
#warning "__unix__ is defined"
#endif

void main() {}
```

Using Intel C++ compiler 19.0.3:

`icpc -o unixpreproc unixpreproc.cpp` shows that both `unix` and `__unix__` macros are defined

but

`icpc -std=c++11 -o unixpreproc unixpreproc.cpp` shows that only `__unix__` is defined.  Is this deliberate?  It is [not documented in the Intel compiler manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-additional-predefined-macros).

Comment: Seems like an oversight in the documentation. Note that if `-std=gnu++11` is used then `unix` is defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's very deliberate. This is explained in the GCC manual (which behaves the same as `icpc` in this respect):

> The C standard requires that all system-specific macros be part of the reserved namespace. All names which begin with two underscores, or an underscore and a capital letter, are reserved for the compiler and library to use as they wish. However, historically system-specific macros have had names with no special prefix; for instance, it is common to find `unix` defined on Unix systems. For all such macros, GCC provides a parallel macro with two underscores added at the beginning and the end. If `unix` is defined, `__unix__` will be defined too. There will never be more than two underscores; the parallel of `_mips` is `__mips__`.
>
> When the `-ansi` option, or any `-std` option that requests strict conformance, is given to the compiler, all the system-specific predefined macros outside the reserved namespace are suppressed. The parallel macros, inside the reserved namespace, remain defined.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html

The `-std=c++11` option requests strict conformance. The `-std=gnu++11` option is the non-strict equivalent, which will define `unix` as well as `__unix__`.

Comment: Excellent GCC documentation! In light of your answer, the best way forward for me will be to use `-std=c++11` and switch to using `#ifdef __unix__`.

Answer (score 5):

I would assume this is deliberate, yes. Under the C++11 standard (and the other formally published C++ standards), conforming compilers cannot declare whatever macros and other global symbols they want, because those could interfere with the program's use of those names. Outside the specific list of standard reserved names (which does not include `unix`), compilers must use macro names starting with a double underscore, which are reserved for the compiler's use.

When you don't specify any language standard the compiler is going with its default behavior, which eschews strict standards compliance in favor of backwards compatibility.